# How to find an element which is not visible but enabled or clickable in Appium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

How to find an element which is **not visible** but *enabled or clickable* in Appium?

I have few elements in an android app who aren't visible but enabled/clickable. I want to wait for these element(s).

Answer (score 1):

Use ExpectedConditions:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver,
                    15))
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                            .id("")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to wait for the element which is not visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .invisibilityOfElementLocated(ByLocator(locator)));
```